# How to remove swap columns in below data getting from SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, swap

I am getting data using below SQL query.

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         c.cdr_id as cdr_id, 
         (select cdr_id 
          from coms_trnsfrmd.cdr_legacy 
          where cgs_cdr_id = k.assc_cdr_id) as associated_cdr_id 
     from 
         cgs_postgres.kl_cgs_associated_cdrs k 
     inner join 
         coms_trnsfrmd.cdr_legacy c on k.cdr_id = c.cgs_cdr_id )temp 
where 
    temp.associated_cdr_id is not null 
order by 
    temp.cdr_id
```

Data is look like below using above sql query.

```
CDR_ID          ASSOCIATED_CDR_ID
123                 456
456                 123
123                 178
178                 123
156                 169
198                 456
456                 198
```

Case 1: if records looks like swap

```
CDR_ID    ASSOCIATED_CDR_ID
 123             456
 456             123
```

I don't need populate both, I need it either first or second record.

Case 2: if there is no swap records like

```
CDR_ID    ASSOCIATED_CDR_ID
156            169
```

I need it direct populate it into target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with your_table
as (
    select *
    from (
        select c.cdr_id as cdr_id,
            (
                select cdr_id
                from coms_trnsfrmd.cdr_legacy
                where cgs_cdr_id = k.assc_cdr_id
                ) as associated_cdr_id
        from cgs_postgres.kl_cgs_associated_cdrs k
        inner join coms_trnsfrmd.cdr_legacy c on k.cdr_id = c.cgs_cdr_id
        ) temp
    where temp.associated_cdr_id is not null
    )
----- The above is your original query. Actual solution is below.---- 


select *
from your_table
where CDR_ID <= ASSOCIATED_CDR_ID

union all

select *
from your_table t
where CDR_ID > ASSOCIATED_CDR_ID
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from your_table t2
        where t.CDR_ID = t2.ASSOCIATED_CDR_ID
            and t2.CDR_ID = t.ASSOCIATED_CDR_ID
        )
```

`not exists` ensures that no two rows have swappable values.

Comment: CDR ASSC_CDR_ID
918771 918775
918771 918779
918773 918785
918775 918771
918776 918784
918777 918785
918779 918771
918779 918784
918782 918786
918782 918794
918782 918802
918782 918807
918784 918776
918784 918779
918785 918773
918785 918777
918786 918782
918788 918795
918794 918782
see above is original data getting from query.                                                            If you check above data there is swap data, I don't want both records, I want only one record either first one or second one.

Comment: Yes, It is correct. I need that data only. I used same query in my pgadmin, I am not getting that data.